# Dynamic Content don't working with Angular Js (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-material

I just added the dynamic content via ajax. but the angular bindings are not working with the dynamic content.
I just found an answer on stack over flow to use $compile. I tried now it works but angular material things are not working now.
Please can someone suggest a solution. 
That would be nice :)

**Update with Code**
consider the following to be added content by ajax.
 var data = md-slider>
this content when added by ajax doesnt work so i did a compile.
 var html = $compile(data)($scope)

and then when we add this to the document via jquery the slider doesn't work.
$('#example').html(html);

Comment: Could you provide the code example.

Comment: We really need the actual code to help see what is wrong. Normally, you place your slider in the HTML, then change the values using a controller, service, etc... I have many controls working with 2 way binding with Angular and Angular Material.